# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.useDeprecatedKafkaOffsetFetching()Z

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I want to show spark dataframe and I used:

```
df.writeStream.outputMode("append").start().awaitTermination()
```

But when I got the error when run this line:

```
21/07/16 01:20:53 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = f243e6e6-c02e-4e70-b5c3-6a821fd33232, runId = 312544cf-fea8-45b4-94a1-c052306538cf] terminated with error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.useDeprecatedKafkaOffsetFetching()Z
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the version of spark and version of dependencies you have added. Make sure both are having the same versions. This will resolve the issue.